# Fade in 2 li's at a time with jQuery

Tags: jquery, list, fadein

Trying to fade in 2 li's at a time in a list getting confused on how to accomplish this. Should I have multiple counters? Use a different function instead of slice? I'm lost. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the JS:

```
$(function() {
    var listItems = $('#listed li'),
        counter1 = 0,
        counter2 = 0,
        counter3 = 2,
        listLen = listItems.length;

    function fadeList() {
      listItems.slice(counter1,counter2).fadeIn(1500, function() {
          counter1++;
          counter2+=2;
          counter3+=2;
          if (counter < listLen)  
              fadeList();
      });
    }
    fadeList();
});
```

Check it out live here: http://jsbin.com/iteri/424/edit

Comment: Where are all the counter variables for?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, just show the first two items of #listed?

Comment: @watson I'd like to fadeIn 2 at a time. So fade in 1,2 then 3,4 then 5,6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.  One way is to use `slice()` and `setInterval()`.  Keep a var that tracks your location and clear the interval when you are done:

```
$(function() {
  var i=0;

  var lis = $('#listed li');

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    lis.slice(i,i+2).fadeIn(1500);

    i += 2;

    if(i+1 > lis.length) {
       clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://jsbin.com/iteri/426/edit)</kbd>

Or more compact, use a for loop, `slice()` and `delay()`:

```
$(function () {
    var lis = $('#listed li');

    for(var i=0; i<lis.length; i+=2) {
         lis.slice(i, i+2).delay(i*300).fadeIn(1500); 
    }
});
```

<kbd>[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sasdj/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

A solution using a `for` loop

```
$(function() {
    var lis = $('#listed li');
    for(var i =0; i <= lis.length; i+=2)
      lis.filter(':eq('+i+'),:eq('+(i+1)+')').delay(i*500).fadeIn('500');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsbin.com/iteri/428/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `listItems.slice(counter1,counter2)` use `listItems.splice(0,2)`.